# PHP form not uploading file

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file, file-upload

I have a PHP form that is inserting information into a database.  It all works except for the file upload.  The filename needs to get placed inside the "image" column in the database table and the file needs to be put in the directory as well.  Funny thing is that this uploader was working yesterday. :-S

Please can someone just review my PHP code and see if i am missing something??  Thanks so much!!

FORM CODE:

```
<form name="upload_announcement" method="post" action="PostAnnouncement.php">
Title: (limit 35 characters)<br />
<input type="text" name="title" maxlength="32" style="width:200px;" /><br /><br />
Message: (limit 500 html characters)<br />
<textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea><br /><br />
Upload Image: (Specs: .jpg format, 255px X 255px, and less than 500kb in size.)<br />
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" style="color:#fff;" />
<br /><br />
Start Date:<br />
<input name="dateStart" type="text" id="dateStartImg" />
<br /><br />
End Date:<br />
<input name="dateEnd" type="text" id="dateEndImg" />
<br /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="customerId" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['customerId']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Announcement" />
</form>`

SUBMIT CODE:<br />
`include('ConfigRead.php');

$customerId = $_COOKIE['customerId'];
$select = mysql_query('select filingName from user where customerId = '.$customerId.' limit 1') or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$selectRow = mysql_fetch_array( $select );
$filingName = $selectRow['filingName'];
$imageFileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];

if((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 500000))
{
  if($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
    header("location:Announcements.php?file=error");
  }else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
    "../Admin/CustomerFiles/Announcements/" . $filingName . "/" . $imageFileName);
  }
}else{
  header("location:Announcements.php?file=error");
}

$sql="INSERT INTO announcements (customerId, filingName, title, message, image, dateStart, dateEnd) VALUES ('$_POST[customerId]','$filingName','$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$imageFileName','$_POST[dateStart]','$_POST[dateEnd]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connRead))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

include('CloseConnRead.php');

header("location:ManageAnnouncements.php?add=success");`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the [multipart/form-data enctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) to your form when uploading files

```
<form name="upload_announcement" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="PostAnnouncement.php">
```

Comment: Oh my...it must be late or something.  I thought i was going crazy - guess i just accidentally removed that or something.  Oh well, thanks a ton for the help!  I'll come back in about 8 minutes to "check" the answer and give you credit for the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `file_uploads` enabled in your php.ini (or using `ini_set`)?  Is the filesize larger than the `upload_max_filesize` configuration option in php.ini?

Look into these others, too:

- max_input_time
- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- post_max_size

Comment: The above answer was my problem.  Just forgot to put the enctype in the form.

Comment: `memory_limit`and `max_execution_time` are not referenced in http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php. Where did you get them from?

EDIT: Now I see `memory_limit` is referenced at http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size