# Why I got Undefined array key and Trying to access array offset on value of type null Error when using $_FILES in PHP

Tags: php

I do this in my cms (Content Management System) in register section. I want to add profile image and I do like w3schools tuts: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.
I do it ant=other file it can but when I run in my file I get an error:
Warning: Undefined array key "profileimg_regis" in C:\xampp\htdocs\DeknoinarakDev\dashboard\run\code.php on line 99

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\DeknoinarakDev\dashboard\run\code.php on line 99

Warning: Undefined array key "profileimg_regis" in C:\xampp\htdocs\DeknoinarakDev\dashboard\run\code.php on line 103

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\DeknoinarakDev\dashboard\run\code.php on line 103

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\DeknoinarakDev\dashboard\run\code.php:103 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\DeknoinarakDev\dashboard\run\code.php(103): getimagesize('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\DeknoinarakDev\dashboard\run\code.php on line 103

This is my PHP code:

```
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["register_btn"])) {
  $target_dir = "img/user/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["profileimg_regis"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["profileimg_regis"]["tmp_name"]);

  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  }
  else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Check file size
  if ($_FILES["profileimg_regis"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Allow certain file formats
  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  }
  else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-background" id="md-regisadmin">
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Admin Account</h2>
        <button onclick="closeModal(document.querySelectorAll('#md-regisadmin'))" type="button" id="dismiss-btn-modal">
          <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="closeModal(document.querySelectorAll('#md-regisadmin'))" id="dismiss-btn-modal"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="md-content">
          <div class="form-modal">
            <div class="form-group md">
            <form action="run/code.php" method="post">
              <!--<label for="username_regis">Username:</label>
              <input id="username_regis" type="text" name="username_regis" placeholder="Username" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group md">
              <label for="email_regis">E-mail:</label>
              <input id="email_regis" type="email" name="email_regis" placeholder="Email" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group md">
              <label for="pwd_regis">Password:</label>
              <input id="pwd_regis" type="password" name="pwd_regis" placeholder="Password" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group md">
              <label for="pwdr_regis">Repeat Password:</label>
              <input id="pwdr_regis" type="password" name="pwdr_regis" placeholder="Repeat Password" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group md">-->
              <input id="profileimg_regis" name="profileimg_regis" type="file"/>
            <!--</div>
            <div class="form-group md">
              <label for="utype_regis">Usertype:</label>
              <select id="utype_regis" name="utype_regis"/>
                <option value="noper">No Permission</option>
                <option value="readonly">Reader</option>
                <option value="mod">Moderator (Only Change Data In Website)</option>
                <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
                <option value="superadmin">Super Administrator</option>
                <option value="godper">God Permission</option>
                <option value="root">Root Administrator</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="register_btn">
              Add Admin Account
            </button>
        </form>
        <button type="button" onclick="closeModal(document.querySelectorAll('#md-regisadmin'))" id="dismiss3-btn-modal">
          <a onclick="closeModal(document.querySelectorAll('#md-regisadmin'))" id="dismiss2-btn-modal">Cancel</a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks if you can help. :)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553492/php-form-not-uploading-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP form not uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553492/php-form-not-uploading-file). But seriously, every file upload tutorial you could ever find would show this and probably mention it. Hard to understand why people still miss this basic info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I find How to fix it.
I forgot `<form>enctype="multipart/form-data"</form>` at the top of the form
Sorry. :)